# Error: Failed to find request token in session, passport js

Tags: express, passport.js

I'm using passport-trello to authenticate with trello account, via express.

```
Error: Failed to find request token in session
```

This error occurs when I've been already redirected to the trello prompt and immediately after I hit Allow button.

Routing:

```
app.get('/auth/trello', passport.authenticate('trello'));

app.get('/auth/trello/callback', passport.authenticate('trello', {
  successRedirect: '/',
  failureRedirect: '/error/'
}));
```

TrelloStrategy:

```
export default () => {
  passport.use(new TrelloStrategy({
    consumerKey: process.env.TRELLO_CONSUMER_KEY,
    consumerSecret: process.env.TRELLO_CONSUMER_SECRET,
    callbackURL: 'http://localhost:3000/auth/trello/callback',
    trelloParams: {
      scope: 'read',
      name: 'CommonFeed',
      expiration: 'never'
    }
  }, (req, token, tokenSecret, profile, done) => {
      let user = {};
      user.token = token;
      user.profile = profile;
      done(null, user);
  }));
}
```

Who knows how to fix this? Thanks, in advance

Comment: Is `token` and `profile` arguments have values?

Comment: With some magic issues is solved, dunno how, can't tell anything. But now `tokenSecret` return an empty object. And even with that - trello auth worked just fine. What is that supposed to be?

Comment: according to documentation doesn't seem that they have secret token at all, just a regular one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out, that `req` happens to be that `tokenSecret`. Just checked this within my app. Strange behavior, but it is what it is. Maybe trello changed something, and `passport-trello` became outdated, dunno. Anyway, big thanks to you, Konstantin, for trying to help.